# What does "$-2,25$ in $\mathbb{C}$" mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

> Which of the following numbers is one of the square roots of $-2,25$
>   in $\mathbb{C}$?
>
> a. $-1,5$
>
> b. $1,5$
>
> c. $1,5i$
>
> d. $2,25i$

I can calculate the square roots of a complex number without problems, what I don't understand here is what this problem is asking me exactly.  What does "$-2,25$ in $\mathbb{C}$" mean?

My book is in portuguese so commas are usually used instead of periods to mark the decimal part of a number (i.e $9,5=9.5$). However, commas and colons are also used to separate 2 different numbers (i.e $9,5$ is sometimes equal to $9;5$).

So I am pretty confused as to what "$-2,25$ in $\mathbb{C}$" might exactly be.

My book says the solution is c. Anyone knows?

Comment: That's just a foreign country's notation for the decimal, it's asking for the square root of $-2.25=(1.5i)^2$. The fact that it is "in $\Bbb C$" just means it's a complex number.

Comment: "one of the square roots of $-2,25$ in $\mathbb{C}$" = "one of the [square roots in $\mathbb{C}$] of $-2,25$"

Comment: And, as Adam Hughes pointed out, in some countries (such as Italy) we use the comma instead of the point, so $0,5=0.5$; *and* the point instead of the comma ($1^\cdot000\text{ or }1.000=1,000$ ) **:)**

Comment: Comma is the decimal separator in Sweden (and probably several other countries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are already interpreting the comma correctly:  $-2,25$ is just another way of saying $-2.25$, and it is indeed a cultural thing.

The "in $\Bbb C$" part is just clarifying that you should be looking for a complex number (i.e., a number in $\Bbb C$) as your answer.  The directions are specifying that it's the square root that's "in $\Bbb C$", not the $-2,25$ that's "in $\Bbb C$".  ($-2,25$ actually is in $\Bbb C$ but that's not really relevant - see my digression below, which is also not relevant.)

Technically the "in $\Bbb C$" is redundant because the square root of any negative number is necessarily in $\Bbb C$.

(And even more technically, "in $\Bbb C$" is redundant because *every* real number [including rationals, irrationals, integers, etc.]) is a complex number with imaginary part zero.  But I digress.)

Basically you want to ask yourself, "Which of these 4 answer choices will give me $-2.25$ when I square it?"

Answer (score 2):

The comma here is just the decimal mark: $-2,25$ means $-\frac{225}{100}$, or $-2.25$ as you may be more accustomed to.  It's not saying "square roots of ($-2,25$ in $\mathbb{C}$)" but rather "(square roots of $-2,25$) in $\mathbb{C}$".  That is, it is asking which of the options is a complex number whose square is $-2.25$.

(The same notation is used in the options, so for instance, $2,25i$ means $\frac{225}{100}i$.)